# SystemVerilog Assertions: Once A is asserted, A remains high until B is de-asserted, and after that A will finally be low

Tags: system-verilog, verification, system-verilog-assertions

I tried to write a assertion:

Once A is asserted, A remains HIGH until B is de-asserted. After that, A will finally de-asserted.

The assertion I wrote was:

```
my_assertion : assert property(
    @(posedge clk) disable iff(reset)
    $rose(A) |-> A throughout !B [->1] ## [0:$] !A) 
else $display("Assertion failed")
```

The assertion failed at the time when A is de-asserted. Guys, can you please tell me where I did wrong in my_assertion? Was " [0:$] " not used correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`##` has a higher priority than `throughout`; See [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16.9 *Sequence operations* Table 16-1.

Therefore `A throughout !B [->1] ## [0:$] !A` is the sample a `A throughout (!B [->1] ## [0:$] !A)`. This fails because `A` is required be high (left side of `throughout`) and low (right side of `throughout`) for the last cycle, which will always evaluate as false.

I believe the desired behavior is: `(A throughout !B [->1]) ## [0:$] !A`

Answer (score 3):

I think you're problem is due to operator precedence. This does not fail when A is deasserted:

```
$rose(A) |-> (A throughout !B [->1]) ## [0:$] !A
```

whereas what you have written is the same as:

```
$rose(A) |-> A throughout (!B [->1] ## [0:$] !A)
```

which can never pass, because `A` cannot be true and false at the same time.

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4Vv9